# Getting error as java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in GetMongo Nifi Processor

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

I am getting the following error while using GetMongo Processor in Nifi:

> GetMongo[id=ca35a94e-7da9-373b-92fa-c961d8108bd4]
>   GetMongo[id=ca35a94e-7da9-373b-92fa-c961d8108bd4] failed to process
>   session due to Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl; Processor
>   Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl",

Mongo query that I am using:

```
{"UpdStmp":{
    "$gt":{
        "$date":"2018-10-30T19:02:00.000Z"
    },
    "$lt" :{
        "$date":"2018-10-30T23:02:00.000Z"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Which version of NiFi are you using?

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman nifi's version is 1.6